# Trouble importing Architectural Interiors as fbx models from online sites into Blender

Tags: texturing, import, .fbx

I am trying to import architectural interiors from online 3d model marketplaces like CGTrader or Turbosquid. My workflow is that I download the fbx file, corresponding textures file and put it in a folder called textures at same level as fbx file. Then goto Blender and import the fbx. What I get after import is always a mesh with no textures applied and totally unlit. No matter whether I choose rendering engine as Eevee or Cycles, the textures never get rendered. In the Shading preview (in lookdev portion), the interior is always dark, even then there are lights included in the downloaded fbx.

For example, consider the free 3d model available here: https://www.cgtrader.com/items/1883142/download-page

I download the bathroom.fbx and texture.rar. Then created a folder and placed the fbx inside the folder and also put the texture folder extracted from texture.rar here, at same leves as .fbx (see in the screenshot, my folder structure [image: my folder structure] ) and here is what I see in Blender [image: Rendered Image in Blender]

As you can see that in the Viewport Shading using Cycles, the whole interior is dark and with spots like its still rendering (even though Blender completed by saying "Rendering Done").

Here is how it should look like:[image]

What am I missing?

If it helps, I am using Blender 2.91.

Comment: Please search for your question before asking. This is a very common question and is already answered many times. This is one very good and detailed answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Thanks @MartynasŽiemys for the response. I had already seen that linked question when researching this issue. The reason I asked is because for some cases, I am able to render successfully. For example: https://www.cgtrader.com/free-3d-models/interior/living-room/cozy-room-98cce965-ef86-4d82-b4cd-0010be9a533b renders just fine. It has a .blend file and a texture folder. When I do the same workflow (put texture folder at same level with .blend file) and open the .blend file in blender, everything is rendered fine. Hence the question, to check if there is a way out.

Comment: I assume it cannot be much more obvious that if the file is made in Blender it will render fine in Blender. It might be helpful to look for assets of this type if you want to save time sorting out materials and lighting. There is a dedicated platform https://blendermarket.com/ for content specifically made for Blender that may be useful. Since Autodesk 3ds Max for some reason is still most popular software for achviz, most assets you can buy online are made for it and you will need to set up materials for Cycles or any other render in Blender manually.

Comment: Thanks for pointer to blendermarket.com. Didn't know that.